# Scikit-learn: StackingRegressor with GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, ensemble-learning

I want a stacked regression where the `final_estimator` is `regfinal` and the `estimators` are `reg1` and `reg2`. For example:

```
reg1 = RandomForestRegressor()
reg2 = KNeighborsRegressor()
regfinal = ridge_regression()
```

I am unsure about the parametrization of the `estimators` so I want to perform a grid search first.
I see two ways.

The **first way** gives `model_A`, which is `StackingRegressor` with two `GridSearchCV` (on `reg1` and `reg2`) as `estimators`:

```
params_reg1 = {some grid}
params_reg2 = {some grid}

grid1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=reg1, param_grid=params_reg1)
grid2 = GridSearchCV(estimator=reg2, param_grid=params_reg2)

estimators = [
    ('rfr', grid1),
    ('knr', grid2)
]

model_A = StackingRegressor(
    estimators=estimators,
    final_estimator=regfinal)
```

The **second way** gives `model_B` which is a `GridSearchCV` on a `StackingRegressor` model with `reg1` and `reg2` as `estimators`:

```
estimators = [
    ('rfr', reg1),
    ('knr', reg2)
]

params_reg_all = {some grid for reg1 and reg2}

stacked = StackingRegressor(
    estimators=estimators,
    final_estimator=regfinal)

model_B = GridSearchCV(estimator=stacked, param_grid=params_reg_all)
```

What are the **differences between `model_A` and `model_B`?**